# Troubles cloning from a git / gitolite / git-web / git-daemon server (Fatal: 'gitolite-admin.git' does not appear to be a git repository)

Tags: ubuntu, clone, git, gitolite

Following [this tutorial on installing git, gitolite, git-daemon, and git-web](http://computercamp.cdwilson.us/git-gitolite-git-daemon-gitweb-setup-on-ubunt) I have successfully completed the entire tutorial and actually added projects gitolite; they show up on git web when I go to `http://servername/`.

Now I'm trying to clone `gitolite-admin.git` to add another project and it spits out the error

```
fatal: 'gitolite-admin.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I can't actually clone any repositories from my server. Here is a bit of info, although I'm not exactly sure what to provide:

1. I can SSH to the server using SSH keys.
2. The gitolite SSH key is working; when I execute the `git clone gitolite@{server_ip}:gitolite-admin.git` it asks me to enter in the passphrase for the key, which does work.
3. `sudo su gitolite` while on the server allows me to `cd` into `/home/gitolite` where the repositories folder and the projects.list is held.
4. `ls` in `/home/gitolite/repositories` shows `gitolite-admin.git` as well as the others.
5. `projects.list` **does not** list `gitolite-admin.git` however it does list `otherproject.git`; if this were affecting the ability to clone, i would assume that it would still work to clone `otherproject.git`, which it does not.

If there is anything else I can provide to give more insight please let me know. Any help is appreciated.

*Note:* I followed the tutorial very closely and only strayed from their configuration at the `sudo apt-get install gitolite` step which is [not available on Ubuntu 10.04](https://serverfault.com/questions/287930/couldnt-find-package-gitolite-on-ubuntu-10-04) so I followed [this article](http://www.philwhln.com/install-gitolite-to-manage-your-git-repositories) for the actual installation of gitolite.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/270688/gitolite-clone-not-working-as-intended. Please give us the content of `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`?

Comment: Write the rest of the "git clone gitolite@..." command that you use to initialize cloning.

Comment: I'll have to post the authorized_keys file tomorrow morning; I'll check out that question as well.

Comment: So you can't clone ANY repositories?

Comment: No, none of them work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up redoing the entire installation using the [installation instructions](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/doc/1-INSTALL.html) on the sitaramc.github.com website; worked first try using the **root method**.

Added new users following the instructions in the [administration documentation](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/doc/2-admin.html).

Works from multiple client computers.

TIL; check the creator's documentation before looking for outsider tutorials.

As another note to people who may be having troubles with this... one of the errors I came across after reinstalling using the instructions above was that `'gitolite-admin' does not appear to be a git repository` this ended up being because I was executing:

```
sudo git clone git@{SERVER_IP}:gitolite-admin
```

rather than

```
git clone git@{SERVER_IP}:gitolite-admin
```

which ended up using the `root` user to try to access the repo rather than the current user, which was already authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify the value of `$projectroot` in `/etc/gitweb.conf`?  It sounds like it should be  `/home/gitolite/repositories` compared to `/var/lib/gitolite/repositories` in the tutorial.

What do you see when you go to `http://servername/`?  The project list?

What about if you go directly to `http://servername/gitolite-admin.git`?

Comment: http://servername/ shows the project list but does not show gitolite-admin.git. The server is local so I can't check http://servername/gitolite-admin.git right now, I'll post back later.